# How to change regex pattern so that it finds each match sequentially

Tags: java, regex

I have a text file where I'm storing certificates with the following syntax:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate is in here.  It's a really long string of characters and looks like garbage.  Each certificate is variable length.
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Another certificate is in here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then, I have code where I try to read the above text file, and examine each certificate one by one.

```
//This copies all of my certificates from a file into a String
String certificates = new Scanner(new File("certificates.txt"), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

//This creates a pattern so that I can examine each certificate one at a time
//(?s) allows this pattern to span several lines.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*-----END CERTIFICATE");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(certificates);

//I attempt to examine each certificate one at a time
while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

However, when I call matcher.find(), it returns the *entire* certificates file.  I think because it finds "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" at the beginning of the file, and then it finds "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" at the end of the file.

How can I change my regex pattern so that it finds each certificate sequentially?

Comment: Did you try using a non greedy `.*` like so: `.*?` ?

Comment: @Jerry, `.*?` did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the below as an example:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
asAasdfO'Psadf-ASDFgrvd-dK;9twqegvb5wetg5089'O0'[U'P4we5AASDSFDevbF54wgwe54-t4g5g54wgsefe4-
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Then the following regex takes 242 steps to pull, and will grow rapidly if the cert is longer:

```
(?s)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*-----END CERTIFICATE
```

242 isn't a lot, but then again, this is a VERY Small Certificate.  I've seen Certificates get pretty long.  I'm not sure if the impact would hurt you too much or not.  However, the following regex only takes 72 steps, and will always be about 72 no matter how long the Certificate is:

```
(-{5})BEGIN\sCERTIFICATE\1\s*(?<Cert>[^-]*(?:(?=\1)|-))*?\s*\1END\sCERTIFICATE\1
```

It may seem more complex.  But when speaking Regex, it is very clear.  Also, it won't include the line breaks after the Begin, and before the End.  Just pull out Matcher.Group("Cert") in order to pull the Certificate.

Breakdown:
First, match Five Dashes.  Set that as Capture Group 1 for ease of use later.
Match "BEGIN CERTIFICATE".  Spaces are ugly in regex and should either be [ ] or \s.
Recall Capture Group 1 with \s (5 dashes).
Trim out Spaces, including Line Breaks with \s*
In the Cert Group, capture sets of text all at once (not lazy) until followed by Five Dashes. (This is recursive).
Match any spaces (including Line Breaks), Five Dashes, END CERTIFICATE, and Five Dashes.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `.*` is a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) expression that matches as many certificate sections as possible. You can limit this match to individual sections by using a reluctant expression by adding a `?` quantifier:

```
Pattern pattern = 
   Pattern.compile("(?s)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*?-----END CERTIFICATE");
```